# Combining binomial probabilities of many independent, non-summable variables

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, geometric-distribution

**TL;DR**: How can I calculate a single number to capture the overall "rarity" of falling at percentiles `L_k` across a large set of `K` non-summable, independent binomial distributions `X_k`, avoiding the above pitfalls?

Hi all, I've searched far and wide for an answer to this question, without success, so I apologize if this question is at all atypical for this forum, or is a bit long.

I am trying to calculate how lucky my character has been in a video game, overall. In general, each item `k` can be dropped with known probability `p_k` after defeating some boss. After `N_k` attempts, `X_k` items have been acquired. Most `X_k` are binomially distributed, although some are more complicated like [Poisson binomially distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution).

I have defined my "luck" for a particular item, `L_k`, to be the chance of having received at most `X_k` items given `N_k`, `p_k`, and given the particular type of distribution. In other words, it's my percentile rank compared to other players in terms of # items received vs. # items expected. For a simple binomial distribution `Binom(N_k, p_k)`, this is just equal to the cumulative binomial probability `Pr(x <= X_k)`.

The trouble I am having is how to combine all `L_k` into an overall luck score, `L = F(L_k)`. Previous answers I've seen on the web have stated that this is also a Poisson binomial distribution, but this wrongly assumes I only care about the total number of items received after combining the distributions of all `X_k`. Secondly, not all `X_k` are binomially distributed, though we can assume this  is true for now if it complicates the answer.

I initially thought that all `L_k` are actually uniformly distributed, because I've defined luck to be my percentile compared to all other hypothetical players. It's equally likely to be at any specific percentile (for example, `floor(L_k * 100) = 2` is just as likely as `floor(L_k * 100) = 99` because, of course, each luck "bucket" (of any fixed size) contains the same number of players.

So, I thought I could combine all `L_k` according to an [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution): "The Irwin–Hall distribution is the continuous probability distribution for the sum of n independent and identically distributed U(0, 1) random variables".

But this actually doesn't make any sense, numerically, after checking the results. Consider you are in the 0.0000001th percentile for number of items `k=1` received, and in the 70th percentile for another item `k=2`. According to the Irwin-Hall distribution, the combined luck / probability would be something like 35%, but this of course must be incorrect given that you were so incredibly unlucky for 1 item but slightly above average for another item. Maybe the idea of summing these variables is just wrong, because they don't represent the same thing.

I have this rough sense that Lucks are (*very* roughly) multiplicative (e.g., being in the 1% percentile for 2 different items is surely rarer than 1 in 100, assuming they're the only items, because you're doubly unlucky), so I discounted all types of averaging methods (harmonic, geometric, regular mean, etc.). I did have decent success combining the "probabilities" *L_k* in [logit space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) by summing log-odds, then converting back, but then I had another issue:

Given many possible types of items (*k > 1000*) it is expected that your **average** luck will deviate a certain amount from 0.5 (or, at least, as the average approaches 0.5 across all items, the sum of logits will diverge from 0). So, summing all of these logits makes it extremely likely that the overall Luck `L` will be nearly 0 or 1, which ruins Luck's interpretation as a *percentile* where you are ranked compared to other hypothetical players in relation to receiving many rare items.

There is also another fundamental flaw where defining `L_k = Pr(x <= X_k)` doesn't make any sense when both `p_k` and `N_k` is very low. Surely confidence intervals of some sort come into play here, since defeating a boss 1 time and not receiving the item means very little.

**So, my question is**: How can I calculate a single number to capture the overall "rarity" of falling at percentiles `L_k` across a large set of `K` non-summable, independent, (mostly) binomial distributions `X_k`, avoiding the above pitfalls?

And as a follow-up, I may want to assign an importance weight *I_k* to each item, indicating either difficulty / time-investment of defeating the boss or the monetary value of the item, though again, it can be ignored if it complicates the question too much.

Comment: bump.....................

Comment: What does "non-summable" mean?

Comment: I meant it to clarify that I'm not asking about the distribution of the sum of $x_1 ... x_N$. I'm instead asking about the chance that $P(x_1 <= y_1)$ and $P(x_2 <= y_2)$ ... or some equally rare scenario. By "equally rare", I mean that you could imagine a scenario where being in 99th percentile for item A and the 90th percentile for item B is roughly equivalent to being in the 95th percentile for both, in terms of overall rarity.

The reason for this distinction is that the items are not interchangeable and thus can't be summed.